How do I show Readdle's *PDF Expert* app toolbar once it becomes hidden (iPadOS)?
I use PDF Expert to read and take notes on PDFs in iPadOS.
The app's tool bar (at the top) hides itself automatically when annotating. Sometimes tapping the edge of the page brings it back, but usually it doesn't. There is no visible indicator of e.g. the program switching modes or states whenever the toolbar is hidden permanently.
This is an issue because, with the toolbar hidden, I cannot "save and close" a PDF. It seems like annotations are not written to the backing storage without this action, so once the app toolbar vanishes for good, the procedure to save work becomes convoluted. I have to open the document in a second window (which now has the toolbar), close the broken window (with toolbar permanently hidden), then return to the new window to save changes and exit.
I'm assuming this is user error, and that PDF Expert silently switches between two modes, one of which has an obscure sequence of actions to show the toolbar? Does anyone know the gesture or secret code to show the toolbar in PDF Expert when the normal method of hold-tapping the edge is disabled?
If relevant, this may be an interaction with the iPad pencil, but I've experimented with switching in and out of that and couldn't find a gesture that recovered the tool bar.
